# Please help me understand basics of running a WinXP cd copy from the cloud. please

Tags: windows-xp, windows-11, compact-disc, cloud, autorun

In 2001, a hospital made several cds with my eeg/mri/pet scan data. I couldn't image needing this data again, so I saved my cd copies to the cloud and discarded the cds.

Now I need to present these cd copies in the cloud to a doctor, ideally via a weblink where he clicks and the app runs.

When inserted into an optical drive, each cd would autostart a lightweight app that allowed the doctor to select from 2 or 3 different "heavy" apps to do imaging or statistical analysis of the data on the cd. The root of each cd has an "*Autorun*" file.

1. There is no way for these apps to run without downloading the entire disk image from the cloud to a local disk, correct?

These cds were created in 2001. So xp for sure? I am new to Windows. My Windows machine is WinPro11. When I double-click on "Xchangeinstaller.exe" in the root directory, the **Program Compatibility Troubleshooter** app starts, but it is never successful. One time, a window titled **Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool** opened and asked for "*Enter the passkey provided by your support professional.*" I've no idea what that means. My machine is a used hp-hz440 that I just bought on Amazon last week.

Comment: There are so many things you would need to tell us that isn't provided.  First of all.. perhaps hunt around your "CD Image" and see if you can figure out the extension of the imaging files and report back in your question and not in a comment.  This isn't hopeless.. but might require quite a bit of back-and-forth to solve.  The image files would probably be quite large (for the day).  Yes, someone like me could probably pull the old exe out and make it work but that isn't what you need.  Lets figure out the file format.

Comment: Also.. add `@SenorCMasMas` to your comments TO ME so I get notified ;) .. other people here are also quite good so listen to all of us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may have better luck setting up a virtual machine and installing Windows XP in it. If your CDs are iso format then you would simply connect the image to the VM. It doesn't help you transfer it over the Internet but does prove that the disk images are valid.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thank you! If running those diagnostic cds by simply clicking a link in an email is not possible I will pivot and try to get them to run on usb thumb drives (or worst case, back onto cds). But, I don't know if cloud disk performance could be adequate for "click on a link", or if it is even possible. Before it was "insert in the optical drive, and the app just ran."

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I GOT IT! these are the resources I have: (1) copies of original CDs, (2) retired mid-2012 macbook pro (intel i5) with cd drive, (3) win-xp install disk with unlock key, (4) several blank cds, (5) 1 thumb drive, might not be large enough.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm smart enough to install xp / copy cds. or just send my copies to doctor. But, modern computers don't have cd drives. So, I've got a worst cast solution. Now, please just give me your advise on how to present my data to doctors in the best format.

Comment: I am double down on the idea that we need to know what the file format is.  A modern viewer might be able to deal with the format or perhaps we can convert them.  I have a nephew that had a C4 injury and I needed to do that same for him to see the images. Can you find one of those files and share information about it?  Many modern image viewing programs support a variety of formats.  It is also possible that the format is proprietary (but probably not).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Each cd is a package with 2 parts, an app to do image / statistical analysis and the data which is in an app specific format. The app just starts when the optical drive closes. I've made copies and sent the originals to the doctors. I'll see if saving iso images onto OneDrive can lead to a better solution. Sorry I didn't know I still had the disks. I'll keep messing around with iso in the cloud, but I've got my worst-case solution. thank you.